# No Video Graphics (Cinnamon Fallback Mode)

Tags: drivers, video, cinnamon, mint

After installing a .package file (LaCie Network Manager), I restarted my computer and the login screen does not appear anymore. I opened the terminal with CTRL + 2 and I could start MDM with `sudo mdm`. The problem is that Cinnamon is working without proprietary drivers (Not software rendered) and is launching in `Fallback mode`.

How can I fix this problem ? Do I have to reconfigure Xorg, Intel drivers, .. ?
Thanks in advance.

I have an ASUS Zenbook Prime (UX31A) with Linux Mint 16.

`lshw -C display`

```
*-display               
 description: VGA compatible controller
 product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
 vendor: Intel Corporation
 physical id: 2
 bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
 version: 09
 width: 64 bits
 clock: 33MHz
 capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
 configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
resources: irq:44 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution !

Start your computer, MDM won't start.
Type `CTRL + F2` to open the terminal.

Force the start of MDM : `sudo mdm`

The GUI will appear, you will need to fix the "video driver error" with Cinnamon because of :
"cinnamon is currently running without video hardware acceleration"

```
sudo update-rc.d -f mdm remove
sudo update-rc.d mdm defaults
```

Then reboot : `sudo reboot`

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question, you saved me a lot of research! :)